# Will a simple C program be compiled to Microsoft's Intermediate Runtime Language or To Machine Code in Windows

Tags: c, visual-c++, compilation

I am new to programming, and I am trying to grasp all of the concepts such as compilation and linking. One of the books that I am reading says that the C code will be compiled into Machine Code. However, the book doesn't assume anything about the environment that we are working on.

I write all of my C source files in Notepad++ and them from the the Visual Studio's command prompt, using the command CL. Are my programs being compiled directly to Machine Code or to the Common Intermediate Language and then to Machine Code?

Wikipedia says: "Languages which target a CLI-compatible runtime environment compile to CIL (MSIL)."
But I don't think that I am targeting the Common Language Infrastructure.

Comment: It is technically possible.  But you'd have to write code using a language extension to C++, no C book will ever show you how to do that.

Comment: Your C code is compiled into an intermediate language (not CIL, of course), which is then compiled into another intermediate language, ..., and only at the very end of this long chain it is translated into a machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS C compiler will compile plain C or C++ code to machine code directly. Well the compiler will pass the code through several layers and intermediate internal representations, but you can consider the compiler a black box and ignore them.

A different thing would be if you were to use C++/CLI. That would be... complicated.

If you use the CL.EXE from the command line, you have to pass an option to enable the CLI (`/clr` I think) so probably you are not using it. Moreover, this is only available for C++, not C.

Comment: Thanks that clears things up for me, I just wanted to make sure the black blox (compiler) wasn't trying to slip anything past me.

Comment: @YW! To take a closer look to your program and what the compiler did, I like to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: You can add /FAs to the command line and see the final generated assembly language without using the debugger.  I believe the Project UI still has an option for generating assembly source as well.  If your program has anything interesting happening, you can also see the assembly is radically different with /Od and /O2 optimization options.  Have fun!